Jandex indexes not built for dependent module in Quarkus Multi-Module setup with Maven in IntelliJ
I use the following versions:

Intellik: 2024.1.4
maven: built-in (3.9.6)
org.jboss.jandex: 1.2.3
Quarkus: 3.12.3

I have the following project structure:
pom.xml
|- libraries
   |- pom.xml
   |- library A
      | - pom.xml
|- services
   |- pom.xml
   |- service B
      |- pom.xml

library A has a service class which is referenced in service B, thus service B needs a jandex index in library A. This configuration is already working: I can start the service properly with quarkus:dev as well as in docker images. Tests triggered via mvn (locally as well in the CI) are working as well (via mvn clean verify -pl services/service-b -am)
The jandex configuration:
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-index</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jandex</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

Anyhow, when starting from a clean project and trying to start the integration tests in service-b out of IntelliJ, it cannot start any test annotated with @QuarkusTest. I also see that the jandex.idx in library A is not generated.
As soon as I triggered any action that executed the phase compile for library A at least once, it's working fine: the jandex.idx file is present.
I tried changing the phase of the jandex plugin as well as adding -am to maven.config, but neither approach made IntelliJ build the jandex file during test.
Delegating the build to maven opened another can of worms (maven CI friendly versions with maven-git-versioning-extension).

Not related to the question, but you use old Jandex. The new Jandex versions (3.0 and above) live under SmallRye: io.smallrye:jandex and io.smallrye:jandex-maven-plugin.

thx for the hint.

Found the following approach which was ok'ish in the end (was automated + didn't add too much time to a test run):

delete all JUnit run configurations
add a Template run configuration which adds a BeforeRunTask. This run task has to be a maven task with the goal jandex.jandex .
Store the template as run configuration.

A ready-to-use example: Copy the following file to .run/Template Unit.run.xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="true" type="JUnit" factoryName="JUnit">
    <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="" />
    <option name="METHOD_NAME" value="" />
    <option name="TEST_OBJECT" value="class" />
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
      <option name="Maven.BeforeRunTask" enabled="true" file="$PROJECT_DIR$/pom.xml" goal="jandex:jandex" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>

This works also on a partial build/clean project as jandex is only executed for already-built classes.
